# How to pass python self object to another python script

Tags: python, callback

I have a strange requirement, in which I need to call a script from python, which I am doing using the subprocess module, and then call a function of original class from the script. I have something like this -

```
import subprocess
import textwrap
import sys
class caller:
  def call_script(self):
     script = textwrap.dedent("""\
          #! /usr/bin/env python
          import caller
          print ("Before the callback")
          caller().callback()
          print ("After the callback")
      """)
     subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True, executable=sys.executable())

   def callback(self):
      print("inside the callback")
```

Ofcourse now I realize that the callback that would be called from script, is not the method of same object which executed the script. Is there any way to pass the self object to the script, or any other way in which I can get the callback method of the original object that called the script ?

Comment: It sounds like you have dug your own grave already ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright as @knitti suggested the script run in a completely different process, so I solved this problem by a combination of signals, files and global variables. Not claiming this to be the most elegant solution but it worked for me -

```
import subprocess, textwrap, os, signal
caller_object = None
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
   caller_object.callback()

comm_file = "/tmp/somefile"

class caller:
   def call_script(self):
     signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, mockproc_callback)
     # Need to pass the process id to the script.
     with open(comm_file, 'w') as pipe:
        pipe.write("{0}".format(os.getpid()))

     # Also set the global object so that callback function could be called by handler
      global caller_object
      caller_object = self

     script = textwrap.dedent("""\
          #! /usr/bin/env python
          import caller, signal, os
          with open("{0}", "r") as pipe:
          # Read the pid of original process
          pid = pipe.read()
          print ("Before the callback")

          # Although its named kill, os.kill could be used to send all sort of signals to a process
          os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGALRM)
          print ("After the callback")
      """.format(comm_file))
     subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True, executable=sys.executable())

   def callback(self):
      print("inside the callback")
```

I am sure there is tons of scope for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The script happens to run in a completely different process, You'd have to devise a way to communicate between processes. 
(For that you can use: Local sockets, possibly the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package, possibly pipes via subprocess) - There's no easy way to pass a meaningfull object reference into another process.